# SFCC- create categories with "sorting_rule" property does not work via API

Tags: rest-api, commerce-cloud

As mentioned in the [API Explorer](https://api-explorer.commercecloud.salesforce.com/) with version 21.3 For the Create categories API i.e

```
PUT/catalogs/{catalog_id}/categories/{category_id}
```

The sample **request-body** mentioned in the documentation is

```
{
  "c_alternativeUrl": {
    "markup": "string",
    "source": "string"
  },
  "c_catBannerID": "string",
  "c_customCSSFile": {
    "abs_url": "string",
    "alt": {
      "additionalProp1": "string",
      "additionalProp2": "string",
      "additionalProp3": "string"
    },
    "dis_base_url": "string",
    "path": "string",
    "title": {
      "additionalProp1": "string",
      "additionalProp2": "string",
      "additionalProp3": "string"
    }
  },
  "c_enableCompare": true,
  "c_headerMenuBanner": {
    "markup": "string",
    "source": "string"
  },
  "c_headerMenuOrientation": "Horizontal",
  "c_showInMenu": true,
  "c_sizeChartID": "string",
  "c_slotBannerHtml": {
    "additionalProp1": {
      "markup": "string",
      "source": "string"
    },
    "additionalProp2": {
      "markup": "string",
      "source": "string"
    },
    "additionalProp3": {
      "markup": "string",
      "source": "string"
    }
  },
  "c_slotBannerImage": {
    "abs_url": "string",
    "alt": {
      "additionalProp1": "string",
      "additionalProp2": "string",
      "additionalProp3": "string"
    },
    "dis_base_url": "string",
    "path": "string",
    "title": {
      "additionalProp1": "string",
      "additionalProp2": "string",
      "additionalProp3": "string"
    }
  },
  "catalog_id": "string",
  "categories": [
    null
  ],
  "description": {
    "additionalProp1": "string",
    "additionalProp2": "string",
    "additionalProp3": "string"
  },
  "id": "string",
  "image": "string",
  "link": "string",
  "name": {
    "additionalProp1": "string",
    "additionalProp2": "string",
    "additionalProp3": "string"
  },
  "online": true,
  "page_description": {
    "additionalProp1": "string",
    "additionalProp2": "string",
    "additionalProp3": "string"
  },
  "page_keywords": {
    "additionalProp1": "string",
    "additionalProp2": "string",
    "additionalProp3": "string"
  },
  "page_title": {
    "additionalProp1": "string",
    "additionalProp2": "string",
    "additionalProp3": "string"
  },
  "parent_category_id": "string",
  "paths": [
    {
      "id": "string",
      "name": {
        "additionalProp1": "string",
        "additionalProp2": "string",
        "additionalProp3": "string"
      }
    }
  ],
  "position": 0,
  "sorting_rules": [
    {
      "creation_date": "2021-03-17T08:17:40.384Z",
      "description": "string",
      "id": "string",
      "product_sorting_rule_steps": [
        {
          "attribute_id": "string",
          "direction": "asc",
          "is_system": true,
          "position": 0,
          "text_relevance_included": true,
          "type_id": "string"
        }
      ],
      "rule_context": "string",
      "site": "string"
    }
  ],
  "thumbnail": "string"
}
```

I am trying to update **sorting_rule** property using this API, but it doesn't seem to work as this property is not present in the response as well, also when I tried updating **link** property it does not work. Attaching the same response below.
What are the correct input property for this API?

[image]